# Does it possible insert encoded ( symbol in source code of webpage, using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, entity

I need to insert to the HTML source code of webpage the round bracket symbol ( encoded in &# 40; format (please, remove space between # and 4 to get encoded symbol).

But if I use .innerHTML= or jQuery.html() or jQuery.replaceWith() or just change the source code in debug tool of Chrome or Firefox – I always get one symbol ( instead of five symbols that I need &# 40;

Is the way to insert encoded round bracket symbol in HTML source code using JavaScript?

Comment: use `innerText` ... or `&amp;#40;`

Comment: innerText put & amp;#40;   (delete space after &) and user see &# 40;  (delete space after #) but I need to my user see only round bracket, that actually &# 40; (without space after #) in HTML source code.

Comment: you complained that `I always get one symbol (` ... now you want just the `(` ... make up your mind  - perhaps if you created a working example of what you are doing, then explain what you expect

Comment: oh, wait ... you want to set the innerHTML using `&#40;` ... you want the browser to **show** `(` - but the innerHTML should remain `&#40;` ? you can't do that

Comment: @JaromandaX exactly!

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is seeing `"&#40"` is translating it. I can't test it now, but I assume that if you escape the ampersand that will work: `"&amp;#40"`